# Isekai manga with time-travel involving a flip phone

Tags: story-identification, anime, isekai

In first episode is that he went to a 7eleven (but then in Japan) and suddenly disappeared into another world (with a flip phone) where magic is relevant. He gets in trouble, but a girl saves him who was also searching for a girl who stole something from her. He offers to help her and then they find a house where it is but they both die in the hands of a women.

I think I also saw the second episode because he then travels back in time and tries to save her, but she of course doesn't recognise him so it doesn't go how it went like the first time.

Comment: When you say 7Eleven, do you just mean 'a convenience store' or literally that brand?

Comment: @Valorum I would guess most likely that brand. 7Eleven convenience stores are very common in Japan.

Comment: @N.Virgo - Assuming my answer is correct, it was actually a 'MINISTOP' (see vid below), which seems to be a real brand in Japan; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ministop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [*Re:Zero - Starting Life in Another World-*](https://myanimelist.net/anime/31240/Re_Zero_kara_Hajimeru_Isekai_Seikatsu) (AKA *Re:Zero kara Hajimeru Isekai Seikatsu).*

> When Subaru Natsuki leaves the convenience store, the last thing he
> expects is to be wrenched from his everyday life and dropped into a
> fantasy world. Things aren't looking good for the bewildered teenager;
> however, not long after his arrival, he is attacked by some thugs.
> Armed with only a bag of groceries and a now useless cell phone, he is
> quickly beaten to a pulp. Fortunately, a mysterious beauty named
> Satella, in hot pursuit after the one who stole her insignia, happens
> upon Subaru and saves him. In order to thank the honest and
> kindhearted girl, Subaru offers to help in her search, and later that
> night, he even finds the whereabouts of that which she seeks. But
> unbeknownst to them, a much darker force stalks the pair from the
> shadows, and just minutes after locating the insignia, Subaru and
> Satella are brutally murdered.
>
> However, Subaru immediately reawakens to a familiar scene—confronted
> by the same group of thugs, meeting Satella all over again—the enigma
> deepens as history inexplicably repeats itself.

Comment: Man. I just finished watching 2 seasons of the anime. It was misery porn all the way. Jesus. Dude couldn't catch a BREAK!